# how to edit the picker view components in eventkit view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, eventkit

I am trying to edit the components of AM & PM wither other text. I am using Eventkit framework. How would I modify those components.

Any idea where I got stuck ?

Comment: no, i have no idea. what did you try? give more info about your problem [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just want to remove AM,PM from pickerview in event kit framework. I am trying to replace it with some other text like breakfast, lunch and dinner for recipe to add events in calendar. give me some idea @nilsK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to edit? If you are using a DateTimePicker, you can set the format and the current time.  You need to provide more details of what you want to do.

Comment: just want to remove AM,PM from pickerview in event kit framework. I am trying to replace it with some other text like breakfast, lunch and dinner for recipe to add events in calendar. give me some idea @Justin Holman

Comment: I am already using this EK event framework and passing this Title and subtitle,date and time also. Now I need to add lunch, dinner at der. Thanks in advance

Comment: The standard UIDatePickerView does NOT allows you to replace elements, there is the UIPicker view, which allows for a custom view. Why would you remove AM/PM, how would a user know they are picking 9:00 am vs 9:00 pm? 9:00 breakfast is very odd. Your code can infer that from what they selected.

Comment: In that situation there is a option like putting 24 hour timing.

Comment: I am already having that idea like UIpicker view, But, I have implemented title passing to event controller and event adding to calendar as per the date. So, If I start to create that manual viewcontroller it needs very lengthy process. Any other idea to change that components.

Comment: Sorry, but you are going to have to write a custom view for this. Apple does not expose the ability to customize the component in that way. You are doing something very non standard and I think it would confuse your users. I would imagine Apple might push back on that as well.